# What's CSS version of <hr noshade/>

Tags: html, css

I know that `noshade` is not supported in HTML5, and they recommend to use CSS to accomplish this... but what is the CSS replacement to this:

```
<hr noshade/>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might work:

```css
hr {
  border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: Use the `border` shorthand.

Comment: why is so much required to do something so simple?

Comment: I actually wanted to point out is was the code of the debugger. But yea fixed that :)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```css
hr {
  background: aqua;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: This allows for 1-pixel horizontal rules. The drawback is, that it may not be printed (if backgrounds are set not to be printed)

Answer (score 0):

This solution will give you a horizontal rule without the shade and also arbitrary thickness (within the limits of `border`).

```css
hr {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  border-top: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```