# How do you keep a button in one place?

Tags: html

I'm writing an experiment in HTML for the first time and I need some help. I have a variable 'varname1' which is a sentence of varying length. Sometimes it takes up one line and sometimes two. At the bottom of the experiment there is a 'submit' button. The problem is that the submit button moves up and down depending on the length of var1, which I think is annoying for participants, who have to keep moving their mouse up and down. How can I keep the 'submit' button in a fixed place regardless of the length of the material above it?

```html
<form action="next" method="post">
  <center>
    <hr noshade width="800" size="3" align="left">
    <p> varname1</p>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;">
      <table border="0" rules="none">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="100">
          <col width="100">
        </colgroup>
        <Question>
          <br> <br>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">yes</td>
            <td align="center">no</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center"> <input type="radio" name="relevance" value="yes" required="required"> </td>
            <td align="center"> <input type="radio" name="relevance" value="no"> </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
  </div>
  <nobr>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You could position the button absolute or you can add a kind of spacer before the button that has for example a max height of 200px and decreases in height when var1 takes up more space. For that you could take a look at flexbox.

Comment: you would first need to fix your html errors - tables cannot contain question or br tags, centre tag is obsolete and should not be used, and the align attribute is also obsolete and should not be used.  There seems to be more closing divs than opening divs

Comment: Use <textarea>, as it has support for multiple lines of input.

Comment: In addition to those listed by @Pete, the following are deprecated elements and attributes: [`noshade`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20225893/215552), `width`, `size`, `border`, `rules`, and `nobr`. `nobr` is also supposed to have an end element, but since it's obsolete, simply add a class to the `p` element and set the `white-space` property to `nowrap` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thank you everyone, and Pete and Heretic Monkey for pointing out other issues.

Comment: vS12: I tried this, but a textarea seems to be an area where users can type stuff, and this isn't what I want.

Comment: Johnny: yes, positioning the button in an absolute place is what I want, but I'm not sure how. I'll try the flexbox thing.

Answer (score -1):

Give the p tag a fixed height like so:

```css
    .output-var {
      height: 60px;
    }
```

```html
      <p class="output-var"> varname1 </p>
```

Comment: Thank you! When I tried this it didn't work: .output-var was interpreted as text and printed on the screen. Did I miss something?

Comment: Make sure you add the CSS in the right place. It is recommended that you have an external CSS file and link it to your html file.

You can also do it inline: `<p style="height: 60px;"> varname1 </p>` and omit the CSS.